# Render personalized data in template against django.contrib.auth.models.User

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

When my users answer a challenge, I want it to be stored against their profile. When they log in, they will see an index of challenges and it will show which ones have been answered.

Like this:

```
Trivia
    What is the capital of France? - answered
    How high is the Empire State building? 
Maths
    What is 2+2? - answered
```

My model for the above contains Category and Challenge. I am also using Django auth User for log-in. To get the 'answered' bit, I thought I could add a User_Challenge model in models.py:

```
class User_Challenge(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    challenge = models.ForeignKey(Challenge, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    answered = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

But because you can't do filtering in a template, I am finding this really cumbersome.

Is there a simpler way to associate challenge status against a user profile without introducing another table? I find that passing Category, Challenge, User and User_Challenge from my view to my template too complicated since you can't execute functions in templates.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You actually can execute functions in template. It is called custom template tags. Since you already have `Challenge` object passed to the template, you could check if the relation between `Challenge` and `User` exists. Custom tag for this case would look like this:

```
@register.filter(name='is_answered')
def is_answered(challenge, request):
    return User_Challenge.objects.filter(
        user = request.user,
        challenge = challenge
    ).exists()
```

In your template you should load custom_tags. You can do it with loading static:

```
{% load static сustom_tags %}
```

And then with your challenge variable:

```
{% if challenge|is_answered:request %}
    do something
{% else %}
    do something else
{% endif %}
```

Custom tags should be stored in a separate folder named `templatetags` within respective app's folder. Beside file with tags folder should have `__init__.py` file. Read docs to understand where to put them better.

In this case your boolean field is redundant. You also could put `User` object into `manytomanyfield` of your `Challenge` model and then check for `User` object presence in it, but you would need to run some kind of checks anyway.

Comment: Wonderful advice. Works amazingly well. Thank you